# how can we add custom fonts to email templates?

Tags: html, css, email, email-templates

I'm designing an email template, but my custom fonts will not effect any text. specially in Persian/Farsi fonts.
so how can  I add some custom fonts to my email template?

Answer (score 3):

The only difference to add custom fonts to email templates is that, by default, *The Outlooks* on Windows will ignore your font stack and fall back to *Times New Roman*. To prevent this, you can add the `mso-generic-font-family:swiss;` in your `@font-face` declaration. (I wrote [an article about this property here](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2019/today-i-learned-about-mso-generic-font-family/).) But if you want to add a Google Font, my favorite way to embed it in an HTML email is to use a conditional comment to wrap the `<link>` element and hide it from *The Outlooks* on Windows.

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Public+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

However, even with this, you must know that `@font-face` support in HTML emails is quite limited. As of june 2021, it works well in Apple Mail (iOS, macOS), Outlook (macOS only), Thunderbird and a very few other clients. It doesn't work in any client from Gmail, Outlook.com or Yahoo. Make sure to check [Can I email… @font-face](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/) for more details.

[image: Can I email… @font-face]

Comment: yeah, you are right. I have to use Google fonts only to make sure it will effect my template in all devices and clients but google does not have any Farsi fonts so I had to use some Arabic fonts and that actually works but not nice enough, anyway thank you for your help.